# AJAX request not working on remote host

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got an AJAX request which pulls the data from the form and POSTs it to an API. The weird thing is it works perfectly fine on localhost but fails silently when I upload to remote server. And I mean silently: the response code is blank, there's nothing in the logs. I've checked on Firefox and Chrome. jQuery is loaded, function is firing properly. The code is below:

```
function send() {
    console.log("preparing");
    var beacon = {
        beaconID: $("#beaconID").val(),
        name:$("#beaconName").val(),
        campaignID:$("#campaignID").val(),
        clientID:$("#clientID").val()
    }
    console.log("payload:");
    console.log(beacon);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../beaconAPI/index.php/createBeacon',
        data: JSON.stringify(beacon),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("done:");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does your url path change on your server?

Comment: `10:33:21.046 "{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}" addBeacon.html:34
10:33:21.046 "AJAX error: error : "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you posted

```
10:33:21.046 "{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,
"statusText":"error"}" addBeacon.html:34 10:33:21.046 "AJAX error: error : "
```

A status code of zero means one of two things:

1. You are running off file protocol
2. The page refreshed as Ajax call is made

Since you said this is on production, sounds like it is a case of #2.

So you need to cancel the action that is causing the page to refresh. Since you do not show how you call send, here is some basic ways of cancelling the action.

```
onclick="send(); return false" 
onsubmit="send(); return false"

$("#foo").on("click", function(e) {
    send();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That page was reloading and I was wondering why. Adding "return false" worked. Thank you so much. I've been trying to get it working since yesterday.